# Qual é a diferença entre o evento canplay e canplaythrough?

Tags: javascript

Ambos os eventos `canplay` e `canplaythrough` são semelhantes, mas qual é a diferença principal entre usar um e o outro?

Comment: O `canplaythrough` é disparado quando não só é possível tocar a mídia, mas tocar até o final sem parar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença é subtil, [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) indica que um objeto está disponível para poder iniciar a apresentação/visualisação. O evento [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) é disparado quando suficiente conteúdo desse objeto já estiver em memória para o browser ter a certeza que é possível mostrar o resto do conteúdo sem interrupções.

Assim se o utilizador iniciar a apresentação antes de `canplaythrough` ter disparado é possível que haja pausas devido ao browser não conseguir carregar o conteúdo a tempo de visualizar o instance que o browser mostra/toca. Enquanto que depois do `canplaythrough` ser disparado o browser já tem "tudo o que precisa" para mostrar o conteúdo sem interrupções.

Comment: Qual é o melhor para mim utilizar? por exemplo, para informar a o usuário que o vídeo está pronto para ser reproduzido.

Comment: @marquinho depende muito. Depende do tipo de conteúdo (se é do tipo de conteúdo que só se vê poucos segundos, ou se o ideal é tocar sem interrupções); depende da qualidade da ligação dos utilizadores e que tipo de transparência a app/interface deve dar ao utilizador; etc